# How to decode this wierd encoding in python?

Tags: python, django, string, python-3.x, decode

I am working with a mobile operator API. When I receive a message in Persian it returns a weird encoding like this.

```
062a0633062a
```

This string represents `تست` in Persian. I know every four character is Unicode representation of Persian character.

How can I decode this kind of encoding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> binascii.unhexlify('062a0633062a').decode('utf-16be')
'تست'
```

Comment: Thank you worked properly. But another question how can i detect a string is english or this kinda string?

Comment: Entire theses have been written about that.